# Find the exact date and time before n months?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, c++-chrono

I am using [HowardHinnant date](http://git@github.com:HowardHinnant/date.git) library in my project. I want to get the exact datetime before n months.

For Example : "2016-12-17 18:21:26" is current datetime and, i want to know the datetime of 13 months before. It should output "2015-11-17 18:21:26".

```
/*
 * This function will return the current date in year_month_day format
 */

auto currentDate() {
    auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    date::year_month_day currentDate = date::floor<date::days>(currentTime);
    return currentDate;
}



/*
 * This function will find the date before (n) months
 */

template <typename T>
auto oldDate(T monthsNum) {
    auto currentDate = currentDate();
    auto yearCurrentDate = (int)currentDate.year();
    auto monthCurrentDate = currentDate.month();
    auto dayCurrentDate = currentDate.day();
    auto yearNum = monthsNum/12;
    auto yearEndDate = yearCurrentDate - yearNum;
    auto monthNum = monthsNum%12;
    auto monthEndDate = monthCurrentDate;
    while(monthNum) {
        monthEndDate--;
    }
    if(monthEndDate > monthCurrentDate) {
        yearEndDate--;
    }
    date::year_month_day endDate = date::year{yearEndDate}/monthEndDate;
    return endDate;
}
```

My function `oldDate()` will return the date which was `n` months before. But i am not able to get the time.

Comment: What if there's no such date e.g. one month before `2016-03-31 18:21:26`?

Comment: @W.F. : In such cases it should return the last date of that month and year. But my function is currently not handling this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `currentDate()`, create a `currentTime` which returns a `sys_seconds` (time with seconds precision):

```
auto
currentTime()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return date::floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
}
```

Now `oldDate` can call `currentTime` instead of `currentDate` and in that way know and preserve the time-of-day.

`oldDate` should take as a parameter `date::months` which is a `std::chrono::duration` with a precision of months.  Here's what it could look like (description afterward):

```
auto
oldDate(date::months monthsNum)
{
    using namespace date;
    auto time = currentTime();
    auto sd = floor<days>(time);
    auto time_of_day = time - sd;
    auto ymd = year_month_day{sd} - monthsNum;
    if (!ymd.ok())
        ymd = ymd.year()/ymd.month()/last;
    return sys_days{ymd} + time_of_day;
}
```

The `using namespace date` is handy otherwise you're going to have `date::` just all over the place.

- First get the time from `currentTime()`.  This is a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, seconds>`, or a count of seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.
- Then truncate this count of seconds into a count of days with `floor<days>()`.  This is a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, days>`.
- One can think of `sd` as a time point to the first instant of the day (in UTC).  So if you subtract `sd` from `time` you get a `std::chrono::duration` representing the time-of-day.  The precision is going to be the `common_type` of the two precisions you're subtracting (`seconds`).
- To do the month arithmetic, you need to switch the type of `sd` from `sys_days` (a `time_point`) to `year_month_day` (a calendar type).  Once you have type `year_month_day`, you can just subtract the `monthsNum` from it, yielding another `year_month_day` (stored in `ymd` above).
- You can check if this resulted in a valid date or not with `.ok()`.  If it is an invalid date, that means you overflowed the days field of the `year_month_day`.  I see in the comments that if this happens, you want the last day of the month.  So just extract the `year` and `month` and use `last` to reset `ymd` to the last day of the month for that year.
- Finally convert the `ymd` back into a `sys_days` (`time_point` with `days` precision) and add the `time_of_day` back to it.

The result is `sys_seconds` (`time_point` with `seconds` precision).

I just ran this with this driver:

```
int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << currentTime() << '\n';
    std::cout << oldDate(months{13}) << '\n';
}
```

And the output was:

```
2016-12-17 15:57:52
2015-11-17 15:57:52
```

[Convenience link to documentation.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)

Comment: I have deleted my answer after seeing so much detailed in one answer. I have also learnt many thing from this answer other than programming part :)